# Http-TCP/IP proxy programming

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, bitcoin

I need to create a server that will receive an encrypted/signed message in form of a http request (Google App Engine), decrypt it/check the signature, and send it over a TCP/IP connection (Bitcoin network). Moreover, it will need to do the same in reverse - receive TCP/IP messages, encrypt/sign them, and send them as a http request. I'm planning to put the server on EC2.

I don't have too much experience with these things, so I'd like to ask - what is the easiest programming language to create something like that in, and what libraries would you recommend for the required usability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first time doing something like this, I would suggest keeping it simple.  Do you really need part of your system running on App Engine and part on EC2?  For a newbie developer I would suggest sticking to one or the other.  If you really need TCP/IP sockets, this will mean EC2 only.  App Engine can not do arbitrary TCP/IP networking - you can only communicate via http and https.  (note that I am unfamiliar with bitcoin's details - perhaps it can operate just fine over https)

When it comes to picking a programming language and web framework, if you don't have any experience at all yet, you might want to find out what the best bitcoin libraries are written in, and start there.